# Code following a For loop won't execute - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, execution

I'm having a strange issue here. I have a For loop inside a sub, and right below it I have a MessageBox function. Everything compiles correctly, however for some reason, if the loop executes and exits successfully, anything outside and below the For doesn't get executed.

```
Public Sub Example()
    For i = 0 To 9
        ListBox.Items.Add(i.ToString)
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("Done")    'This doesn't execute
    Beep()                     'Doesn't either
    Label.Text = "Done"        'etc.
End Sub
```

Yes, it displays only 10 items in the ListBox afterwards.

I've searched everywhere, but I did not find anything related to such an issue.
I'm kinda puzzled, anyone got a clue of what's going on?

EDIT: Forgot to specify, the sub is actually a TextBox.TextChanged event

Comment: I just tried it in a VB.net Application and I called the Example() function on a button click and it is working as expected. The message box shows, a beep is heard and the Label text changes. How are you calling the Example() function ? Also you could try stepping through the debugger with a breakpoint at the beginning on the loop to see where execution is cut off.

Comment: I think I found the problem, it seems the ListBox.Items.Add contained a null value on the last iteration. Fixing that seemingly solved it. I'm not sure why it wouldn't stop the execution and return an error (newbie here). Thanks for the help, thought.

Comment: If this as you said is executed whenever the text in TextBox changes, then try adding the handler to the sub just to be sure. The header of the sub should be something like : `Sub Example() Handles TextBox.TextChanged`

Comment: @AgentRev, Post your own answer and select it as the correct answer.

Comment: When the system allows you to, you should post your solution as an answer.  After a couple of days, you can select it as being the solution.

Comment: @Michael That couldn't be any more of a coincidence!!

Comment: "Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 6 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the ListBox.Items.Add contained a null value on the last iteration. Fixing that seemingly solved it. I'm not sure why it wouldn't stop the execution and return an error (newbie here).

Comment: Which goes to show to posting *real* code snippets is very important.  Remove the Try/Catch statements.